# How to sum each value inside array of object to new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data like this :

```
const fund = 
[
 {
  id: 1234,
  totalAmount: 0,
  data: 
   [
    {
     id: 1234,
     amount: '4.000'
    },
    {
     id: 1234,
     amount: '3.000'
    }
   ]
 },
 {
  id: 12345,
  totalAmount: 0
 },
 {
  id: 123456,
  totalAmount: 0
  data: 
   [
    {
     id: 123456,
     amount: '3.000'
    },
    {
     id: 123456,
     amount: '5.000'
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

I want to sum the `amount` inside of `data` each id to a key called `totalAmount`. But not all the parent `id` have `data` key.

here's my desired output :

```
const fund = 
[
 {
  id: 1234
  data: 
   [
    {
     id: 1234,
     amount: '4.000'
    },
    {
     id: 1234,
     amount: '3.000'
    }
   ],
  totalAmount: 7000
 },
 {
  id: 12345,
  totalAmount: 0        
 },
 {
  id: 123456,
  data: 
   [
    {
     id: 123456,
     amount: '3.000'
    },
    {
     id: 123456,
     amount: '5.000'
    }
   ],
  totalAmount: 8000
 }
]
```

I was trying with this code :

```
fund.forEach((elA, i) => {
        if (elA.data) {
          const total = funders[i].data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc += parseInt(curr.amount.replace(/\./g, ''))
            return acc
          })
          fund[i] = total ? {...elA, totalAmount: total} : elA;
        }
      })
```

But it's not summing like i want.

Where's my mistake ?

Please ask me if you need more information if it's still not enough to solve that case.

Comment: You're looping over `fund`, but then accessing `funders[i]`. Why not just use `elA.data.reduce()`?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `total`.

Comment: You need to provide an initial value argument to `reduce`.

Comment: You don't have a `loanAmount` property, it's just `amount`. And I don't know why you're replacing all the `.`, it's not a string. Did you copy that code from somewhere else that's processing a different data structure?

Comment: my bad, i was just trying to change the variable name from my workspace. Actually the amount was string in my case

Comment: i was trying your solutin with ```elA.data.reduce()```, but the result like this 
```[object Object]40003000``` for ```id: 1234```
what's wrong with the code ?

Comment: ohh is that because of the ```amount``` was in string format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the initial value for the *reduce* iterator.

```
fund.forEach((elA, i) => {
        if (elA.data) {
          const total = funders[i].data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc += parseInt(curr.amount.replace(/\./g, ''))
            return acc
          }, 0)
          fund[i] = total ? {...elA, totalAmount: total} : elA;
        }
      });
```

Another alternative for the same code:

```
fund.forEach(elA => {
  if (elA.data) {
    const total = elA.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return acc + parseInt(curr.amount.replace(/\./g, ''))
    }, 0)
    elA.totalAmount = total;
  }
});
```